# After opening a PDF using tkpdfviewer, if I try to open another file, it gets appended ahead of it

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, tkpdfviewer

I used `tkpdfviewer` to display PDF on a tkinter window (toplevel). After opening a PDF file, the other files are appended behind the previous files. How do I fix this?

```
file = fd.askopenfilename() # Get the location of the PDF file

if '.pdf' in file:
    pdf_viewer = Toplevel(self.root)
    pdf_viewer.title(f'{APP_NAME} - {VERSION} [PDF VIEWER]')
    pdf_viewer.geometry("650x750")
            
    v1 = pdf.ShowPdf()
    pdf_display = v1.pdf_view(pdf_viewer, pdf_location=file)
    pdf_display.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    pdf_viewer.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to (and shouldn't) call `mainloop()` on an instance of `Toplevel`. Your `root` window, which I assume to be an instance of `Tk`, should be the main GUI loop (i.e., `root.mainloop()`)

Comment: Okay, I will keep that in mind, thank you. Anyways, I have updated the question since I realized that the PDF's were getting appended on the previously opened PDFs

Comment: My answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70293648/5317403) may help.

Comment: Hey, your answer did help but I ran into another issue now. I am unable to keep 2 PDF's open in different tkinter windows(toplevel). I understand that's because we remove the first PDF from the list, but is there any way I can start both PDFs?

Comment: For the current design of `tkPDFViewer`, you cannot.  `tkPDFViewer` has not been updated for over two years, and it does not work with latest `PyMuPDF` module, so it is not recommended to be used.  Try using `PyMuPDF` directly to create your PDF viewer instead.